# get missing data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables "Admission" and "EmailAddress". during the admission process if someone signed up for "paperlessCommunication", the system should add their email in EmailAddress table. due to some coding bug some of the admission, who signed up for "paperlessCommunication", has the missing email address in the emailAddress table. how can I find all the records who are signed up paperless communication but missing records in the email address... P.S. email address table has the email address from some other processes too, I am just interested in one which is missing from admission process with the paperless flag set as "Y".

```
select * from Admission a where a.paperlessCommunication = 'Y'

select * from EmailAddress
```

both tables have personid column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions

Solution #1

```
select *
from Admission A
where paperlessCommunication = 'Y' 
and not exists (select 1 from EmailAddress ea where ea.emailaddress = A.emailaddress);
```

Solution #2

```
select *
from Admission A
where paperlessCommunication = 'Y' 
and emailaddress not in (select emailaddress from EmailAddress where emailaddress is not null);
```

Solution #3

```
select *
from Admission A
left join EmailAddress EA on Em.emailaddress  = A.emailaddress 
where paperlessCommunication = 'Y' 
and EA.emailaddress is null
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select *
from Admission a
where a.paperlessCommunication = 'Y' and
      not exists (select 1 from EmailAddress ea where ea.emailaddress = a.emailaddress);
```

This assumes that the email address is in both tables.  If not, some other id certainly does and that would be used instead.